# How to count json object item?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm parsing a JSON string in Android which looks like this:

```
 [
   {
     "id":70,
     "selection":"25"
    },
    {
      "id":71,
      "selection":"50"
    },
    {
      "id":72,
      "selection":"50"
    }
 ]
```

Now I want to get the total count of all `selection` and display it inside a textview. Can anyone give me an example how to do this, or any tutorial about this?

For example:

> selection 25 = 1
>   selection 50 = 2

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
        JsonArray selections = new JsonArray(); // This is your parsed json object
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
        for (JsonElement element : selections) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            if(jsonObject.has("selection")) {
                int selValue = jsonObject.get("selection").getAsInt();
                if(count.containsKey(selValue)) {
                    count.put(selValue, count.get(selValue) + 1);
                } else {
                    count.put(selValue, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

What this will do is loop over your json array and get the value of each selection element. To keep track of the count it increments the count inside of the `count` hashmap.

You can then get the count for a specific value from the hashmap:

```
count.get(25); // returns 1
count.get(50); // returns 2
// etc...
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the exact implementation may be different. For this implementation google gson was used. Depending on the exact json lib a slightly different approach may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Jackson` in Java 8, you can first convert the given JSON string to `List<Map<String, Object>>`, then transform it into `List<Integer>` for **selection**. Finally, you can count occurrences in this list as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, Object>> jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});
Map<Integer, Long> counted = jsonObj.stream()
        .map(x -> Integer.valueOf(x.get("selection").toString()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(counted.toString());
```

Console output:

> {50=2, 25=1}

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> datacount = new ArrayList<>();


            jsonStr = "Your JSON"

            JSONArray jsonArr= null;
            try {
                jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    //here you can set to TextView
                    String selection = jsonObj.getString("selection");
                    //System.out.println("adcac"+selection);

                    if (data.contains(selection)) {

                        int index = data.indexOf(selection);

                        int count = Integer.parseInt(datacount.get(index))+1;

    //                    System.out.println("Index==="+index+"---count---"+count);
                        datacount.set(index,String.valueOf(count));
                    } else {
                        datacount.add(String.valueOf(1));
                        data.add(selection);
                    }
     // Here you can get data and data count...  
    //                System.out.println("data---"+datacount.toString());
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get the array of the json and iterate and calculate the sum of the selection

```java
JSONArray selections = jsonObj.getJSONArray("selections");

// looping through All Selections
int totalCount = selections.length();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what the user asked. This counts a total of the overall selection while the question seems to refer to a total of selection occurance. (a count, not a sum)

Comment: sorry ,yes you are right I miss understood the question

Answer (score -1):

Why doesn't anybody use Json Path to solve this in two lines?

Comment: Please use your commenting privilege to ask clarification questions. Or [edit] this into an answer according to [answer].